# C Semaphore strange precedence behavior

Tags: c, concurrency, semaphore

I'm practicing with concurrency in C, and I seem to encounter some problems with semaphores.
I'm using Xcode 6.3.2 in MacOSX.

Here it is a sample program that seems to act strangely: the purpose of the example is to print either ABCD or BACD strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

void *thread1(void*);
void *thread2(void*);

sem_t *sem0, *sem1, *sem2;;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    pthread_t t1, t2;

    sem0 = sem_open("sem0", O_CREAT, 0600, 2);
    sem1 = sem_open("sem1", O_CREAT, 0600, 0);
    sem2 = sem_open("sem2", O_CREAT, 0600, 0);

    // quick check
    if (sem0 == SEM_FAILED || sem1 == SEM_FAILED || sem2 == SEM_FAILED) {
        printf("Something went wrong\n");
        return 0;
    }

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, thread2, NULL);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    sem_close(sem0);
    sem_close(sem1);
    sem_close(sem2);

    return 0;
}

void *thread1(void* arg) {
    int n=0;
    while (n<10) {
        sem_wait(sem0);
        printf("A");
        fflush(stdout);
        sem_wait(sem1);
        printf("C");
        fflush(stdout);
        sem_post(sem2);
        n++;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *thread2(void* arg) {
    int n=0;
    while (n<10) {
        sem_wait(sem0);
        printf("B");
        fflush(stdout);
        sem_post(sem1);
        sem_wait(sem2);
        printf("D\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        sem_post(sem0);
        sem_post(sem0);
        n++;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

If I implemented correctly the semaphores, the result would be either ABCD or BACD, but in reality I get a whole variety of strange output.

I will include part of that output here

```
ABCD
BAD
CABCD
BAD
CBAD
CBAD
CBAD
CBAD
CBAD
CBAD
C
```

Is someone able to help me? Thanks in advance

IMPORTANT EDIT:
I downloaded Ubuntu, and the code is working smoothly there, no problems at all. So, to resume

- MacOSX 10.10.3 with Xcode 6.3.2 --> Not working properly
- Ubuntu 15.04 --> Working properly

Don't know why.

Comment: @CrApHer do you know if it returned an error and/if it did, the behaviour of sem_wait on a SEM_FAILED semaphore argument?

Comment: Your thread functions have the wrong signature.  They should each accept an argument of type `void *`, even if they don't use it.  Indeed, your compiler should be warning about a pointer type mismatch.

Comment: Testing your code on Fedora 21, I very reliably see the sequence "BACD\n" printed every time, for thousands of iterations.  This is plausible -- but not guaranteed -- behavior.  I don't see anything in your code that explains the unexpected output you highlighted.

Comment: @Ivano Did this happen the first time you ran the program, or on subsequent invocations?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I edited the thread signature, that didn't change anything, but thanks for pointing that out for completion.
About your testing on Fedora, could it be that under MacOSX environment something is acting strangely, while under pure linux the result would be as expected?

Comment: @WalterDelevich I modified the code with basic error checking after semaphore creation, but I never get SEM_FAILED errors and the semaphores are created correctly.
Also, this happens all the time, maybe you were referring to the semaphores not being closed, I fixed that as you can see in the code, it solved another problem I had (after first run, the semaphore start value was ignored due to not correctly closing the semaphore before) but not the strange behavior. Thanks for pointing that out nonetheless.

Comment: Instead of just calling `sem_wait()` try `while (sem_wait(&sem) == -1 && errno == EINTR);` to make sure that something isn't interrupting your waits (for some reason).

Comment: @MichaelBurr tried, the issue still remains. I'm downloading ubuntu in order to test the code under linux environment, as a last attempt to make the code properly working.

Comment: @Ivano As I understand OSX is based on BSD, maybe you can try with OpenBSD or FreeBSD to see if the OS have the same behavior. According to your question, maybe this site (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sem_open.2.html) can help.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to create and save the values in an `char*` variable to see if the same problem continues.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably that `printf` output is buffered and shared between threads. You'd have to ensure to empty the buffer with `fflush` before posting on the semaphores.

Comment: In one of my own previous program, which use `mutex` & `condition`, I also found the `printf()` wild, after I add `fflush(stdout)`, the output in console become totally correct, so I think this answer is absolutely correct in case op write the concurrent part correctly. By the way, `fflush()` tooks time, in my program it makes the frequence of threads switch different, or the execution of threads become more ordered, so after prove the program is correct with `printf()` and `fflush()`, just uncomment both of them.

Comment: I'm not sure if I implemented correctly your changing, you can see the modified code in op, but I keep obtaining strange output.
I really don't see why, could it be related to the fact I'm on MacOsx and not in pure Linux?

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo when you call `sem_open()` for `sem2` - the name passed in is `"sem1"`:

```
sem1 = sem_open("sem1", O_CREAT, 0600, 0);
sem2 = sem_open("sem1", O_CREAT, 0600, 0);
//               ^^^^
```

So the pointers `sem1` and `sem2` would be referring to the same semaphore.

Comment: thank you for noticing, I edited the code, but the strange behavior still incredibly remains.
Ubuntu is almost downloaded, I will try running in that environment as a last hope.

Comment: I see that you have also updated the example output - so the behavior at least changed?  Can you try wrapping the calls to `printf("A");` and `printf("B");` inside a pair of `flockfile(stdout)`/`funlockfile(stdout)` calls (and maybe remove the `fflush()` calls - I don't believe they should be necessary)? According to my understanding of POSIX, `printf()` should already be doing the equivalent so I wouldn't expect a difference, but I think it's worth an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Printf is accessing one resource, the standard out file descriptor. You need to request a lock to allow access to stdout by only *one thread* at a time. Otherwise you may get interleaved text. I'm not sure why you're creating three semaphores, but consider that if you have multiple semaphores blocking the same resource, you have multiple windows open to that resource. If you only close one at a time, then  you're not really blocking the resource at all.

**edit**:
An example. thread 1 locks sem 0, thread 2 waits. thread 1 unlocks sem0 and thread 2 can continue. Thread 1 now locks sem1. *They're both writing to standard out though*. That means that they both, even obeying your locks, are allowed write to stdout.

Why it doesn't happen earlier is just due to thread contention.

**edit 2**:
I think John's right in that my original explanation doesn't cover your question. I can't reproduce your output, and I can't imagine a path to your output. Even with the fflush example someone else mentioned, I still don't see how that particular string would be formed even using the same buffer with the way your semaphores should be working. I can only guess to this:

1. Your semaphores are named and you don't destroy them. That means they persist between invocations of your program. If you ended your program at just the right time, the semaphore values may be in a state you wouldn't expect(*they ignore the value parameter of sem_open if the semaphore exists*). *Maybe* that could lead to your output.
2. You're not checking return values of your sem functions, they can return errors. Calling subsequent functions on invalid semaphores should return immediately, thereby leaving your printfs only subject to thread contention.

Comment: The point of the code, multiple semaphores, etc. is to allow for the 'A' and 'B' to be printed in either order (i.e. interleaved exactly as you say may happen), always followed by 'C' and 'D' in fixed order.  It is not obvious to me at this point why the provided code does not achieve that.  Your answer is ok in a general sense, but it doesn't adequately address the specific scenario presented in the question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me that I was not closing the semaphores, now I did that and it solved another strange behavior I had (starting value of semaphore was ignored due to not correctly closing the semaphore before)

I'm also checking the return values of semaphores now, as you can see in the edited code in op, but the strange issue stil remains.